# DIV besides page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am designing a wordpress-blog and i am trying to add a div with advertisements besides the main page are.

Centered on the page is a div called wrapper, and to the right side i want to add a div with 250px width.

I got the div on place, but on smaller screens the advertisements overlaps the page. And when i got them not to overlap, the page wasn't centered and on smaller screens the divs appeared under the main page area.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can try a table layout.  Tables are useful when you want to control positioning but still allow the contents to stretch out the container.

```
<table style="border:none; width:100%; margin: 0; padding:0;" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr><td valign="middle" style="text-align:center;">Your content here</td></tr>
</table>
```

The code above is a good way to make an invisible table in which you can specify columns and row layout.  I wrote a single, centered row/col as an example.  Can't remember if it is "valign" or v-align" so try it both ways.

Because it is a "relative" element, other elements should respect its positioning as long as they are "relative", too.

Comment: Thank you for your help but still I don't know how to use that code.  Should i put my wrapper thing in there?